# Walls VCAM flash AS2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

So I have 2 squares. One is blue, With the instance name "mouse", And has the code:

```
onClipEvent (enterFrame) {

    this._x = _root._xmouse;
    this._y = _root._ymouse;
}
```

The other is red, With the instance name "mouseface", And has the code:

```
onClipEvent (enterFrame) {
    _x += (_root.mouse._x - _x) / 3;
}
```

And then i have a vcam with the code:

```
onClipEvent (enterFrame) {
    _x += (_root.mouseface._x - _x) / 40;
}
```

The idea is the blue square stays on top of the mouse, And the red follows the blue, But is slower, And the vcam follows the red. With the vcam and the red square only moving on the x axis. The code is probably very redundant and bad; But it works so i'm going to continue using it.

Anyway, Im wondering how to make the vcam stop at 2 certain x coordinates, Something like five nights at freddys.

Any help is much appreciated, Thanks! :)

Comment: I just tried to add a wall where i want the vcam to stop, Gave it the instance name "wallright" and added this code to the VCAM 

            onClipEvent (enterFrame) {
     _x += (_root.mouseface._x - _x) / 40;
     if (wallright.hitTest)
     {
      this._x -= (5);
     }
            }

I think i screwed up around the "this._x -= (5);" part, And even if it did work i think with the way i have it set up it would just sort of bounce off the wall instead of stopping completely. and sorry about the formatting, every time i hit enter it posts the comment

Comment: please add your update as an edit to the original question.  then you can keep the formatting.